# Set Matte not masking layers the same

Tags: after-effects, effects

I am trying to use a shape layer with set matte to mask off everything behind the screen, but it does not appear to be working here is a video

Please help

Comment: Try pre-comping the shape layer.

Comment: the layer you're using as a matte needs to have a fill effect applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about Set Matte, but you could try setting the transfer mode of the shape layer to Silhouette Alpha? That will cut out everything beneath that layer.

(You currently have the transfer modes hidden. Right click on the title bar above your layer names, click to Columns->Modes)